# Using fixedBreak argument in R package "classInt"

Tags: r, rworldmap

I am attempting to use the `classInt` package in conjunction with `rworldmap` package in R to construct a choropleth. I want to use the `fixedBreaks` argument to specify given breaks.

My data looks like this:

```
> head(Maji)

 Country       waterused  CC
 Afghanistan   36        AFG
 Albania        4        ALB
 Algeria       52        DZA
 Angola         0        AGO
 Antigua       10        ATG
 Argentina      4        ARG
```

`waterused` is a percentage (range:0-4600) and `CC` is the country code (IS03-alpha).

When I attempt,

```
classInt <- classIntervals(ww[["waterused"]], n=5, style="fixed", fixedBreaks=c(0,25,50,75,100,4565))
**Warning message:
      In classIntervals(ww[["waterused"]], n = 5, style = "fixed", fixedBreaks = c(0,  :
      var has missing values, omitted in finding classes**
```

I've tried a number of variations of the argument `style` and have not been successful and consequently my map is not correct. Further, my data frame has no missing data points. Do you have any suggestions/ is there an obvious fix?

Comment: This types of questions are really hard to answer without seeing the full data. Could you please post it as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax. I copied it to my own dataset and changed the dataframe name and variable name and altered the min/max value and it worked perfectly.

Your problem lies in your assumption that your dataset does not contain any missings. I'll demonstrate using an example dataset (like Victor K. argues).

```
id        <- c(1:10)
waterused <- c(0, 10, 20, 60, 80, 91, 92, 93, 94, 4565)
classInt  <- classIntervals(ww[["waterused"]], 
                 n=5, style="fixed", fixedBreaks=c(0,25,50,75,100,4565))
```

This results in no errors + you can check so by running:

```
str(classInt)
```

To replicate your error I'll now add a missing value to 'waterused':

```
ww$waterused[3] <- NA
table(is.na(ww$waterused))    # 1 missing and 9 non-missing values
classInt.na     <- classIntervals(ww[["waterused"]], 
                       n=5, style="fixed", 
                       fixedBreaks=c(0,25,50,75,100,4565))
```

This results in precisely the same error you report. So please check again for any NA's in your 'waterused' variable.